# Storing a link name in a js variable html over multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am actually using css and html and js.

I have 6 category pages (e.g category1, category2, category3, ...) that point to the same page (e.g. fixed) and that pages points to other 3 pages (e.g. Endpage1, Endpage2, Endpage3).

I've added a nav bar to help user don't get lost on the website.

The Navbar is structured like:

```
 Category > fixpage > Endpage
     e.g.)[(Category1 >>> fixpage >>> Endpage3]
```

when I am in category page it just show

```
category1 >>>
```

when I click to link I go on fixpage and the navbar show

```
<a href="#"> category1 <a> >>> Fixpage
```

I manage (thanks to a user here on stackoverflow) to do a function that pass the starting page with get method `?page=category1` in the link  and then it write it on the navbar of the Fixpage

with this function http://fiddle.jshell.net/KFmG8/1/

Now the problem is that when I am on Endpage it shows

```
undefined >>> Fixpage >>> Endpage1
```

and when from Endpage i want to go back to Fixpage,  the variable is lost too so it shows

```
undefined >>> Fixpage
```

can I do something or is better switch to cookies/session?

Comment: I would recommend cookies. `document.cookie="firstpage=cat1"; var cookie = document.cookie;` You may take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp .

Comment: if i use cookie and a user doesn't accept cookie, my whole webpage will be unusable?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a more complex value as the page query parameter to handle the series of parent pages.

```
?page=category1/Fixpage
```

Here is something along the lines of what I mean pulling out some of the code from your fiddle link. qs.page is setup to read like a URL path and then the buildPageStr function will build out the display inside the link HTML.

```
function fillLink()
{
    qs = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
    alert(qs.page);

    var pageStr = buildPageStr(qs.page);

    document.getElementById("backLink").href="c:/sito2/risorse/prove/" + qs.page;
    document.getElementById("backLink").innerHTML = pageStr;
}

//Removes the '/' and places ' >>> ' between each page name
function buildPageStr(tokens) {

    if(tokens) {
      return tokens.split(/\//).join(' >>> ');
    } 

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your title question, there is no way to store values IN JavaScript over multiple pages.  The JS context gets cleared and rebuilt on each page view.  So it seems you are actually asking a more practical question of how to maintain state, or even simpler, how to manage breadcrumbs over multiple pages without server-side session data.

Since you are already pulling one page out of the query string, it shouldn't be much more difficult to build the entire breadcrumb in the query string.

So something like:

```
?pages=Startpage.Fixpage.Endpage
```

Would give you the full breadcrumb path in the URL.  Then instead of displaying the value directly you split it back into pages

```
var pages = qs.page.split('.');
```

You can, of course, use cookies instead but you'd have the same problem really.  You need to manage your entire list of breadcrumbs as the user navigates from page to page.  And it's easy enough to just do that by "serializing" the array of pages into a string and then splitting it back up on the other side.  Using the query string has the added benefit of producing the same breadcrumbs based on the URL regardless of the state of the user's cookies.